# visual studio with c# SocketException: No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it 127.0.0.1:8080 error

Tags: c#, visual-studio, port, sikuli, imageprocessor

I am getting this issue: No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it 127.0.0.1:8080.I use Sikuli4net library but scrn.click dont use metod

```
namespace deneme;
using System;
using Sikuli4Net.sikuli_REST;
using Sikuli4Net.sikuli_UTIL;
public partial class Form1 : Form
{    
   public Form1()
   {
       InitializeComponent();
   }    
   private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {
   }
   private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {
       APILauncher launcher = new APILauncher();
       launcher.Start();
       Pattern pattern1 = new Pattern(@"C: \Users\Ramesh\Desktop\Images\Dc.png");
       Screen scrn = new Screen();
       scrn.Click(pattern1);
   }
}
```

While doing so I get this error:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f9HvM.png)

Comment: Are you supposed to have something running locally that is listening on port 8080? Sounds like there isn't.

Comment: Doesn't look like you initialized a session or have anything listening. This code might help: https://answers.launchpad.net/sikuli/+question/672323